# Angular radio button :checked

Tags: css, angular

In ye ole plain html and css I can do the following:

```css
input:checked+label {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <input type="radio" id="template-1" name="template" value="template1" checked>
  <label for="template-1">Example 1</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <input type="radio" id="template-2" name="template" value="template2">
  <label for="template-2">Example 2</label>
</div>
```

However, when I try to use the exact same snippet inside an angular form with `ngModel`, the css does not initially apply on load. Instead you have to click one of the buttons before it applies.

[angular plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dDkbiDf7Wp1qfZ4ZSTuE?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

It appears that the radio button is not respecting the `checked` attribute? How can I get my angular radio button to begin checked and also apply the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your component as below

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
        <div *ngFor="let example of examples" class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="radio" id="example.value" name="example" [(ngModel)]="template" [value]="example.value">
      <label for="example.value">{{example.display}}</label>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`input:checked + label{background-color: #f00;}`]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
  name = 'Angular';
  public examples = [
    { value: 1, display: 'Example 1' },
    { value: 2, display: 'Example 2' }
];
 template:string;


ngOnInit(){
   this.template = this.examples[0].value;
  }
}
```

Also created one plunkr

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Gsei7dfH4zw3JYrqaou?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Pluker

http://plnkr.co/edit/xCZKeAx8Q2e2Ge5istuE?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview

```
  <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="radio" id="template-1" name="template" value="template1" checked = "{1 == 1}">
        <label for="template-1">Example 1</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: This isn't working properly with form. Even though the initial value is set, it's not reflected in the form value: http://plnkr.co/edit/cXfkRAsYNoWPWjNw5Zqp?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview ALSO it's not reflecting value back to `template1` when that radio is clicked...

Comment: @AJT_82 yup i am trying to figure that out it not reflecting as we dnt have ngModel attr . we need to bind the checked to ngModel but its not happening

Answer (score -2):

This answer is for AngularJS. OP wants answers for angular...

With angular you can also add an class depending on the value of the ng-model

`<input type="radio" ng-model="bool" ng-class="bool ? 'true' : 'false'">`

This should add the class "true" when $scope.bool is true (or the radio is checked)

Didn't test this, but it should work or at least help in someway.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for angular not angularJS.