# How do i bind two radiobuttons to a data model?

Tags: java, angular

I have an account update form. In that form I can set whether the account is enabled or disabled. When the update form gets loaded I would like the radiobutton group to be checked according to the database value (enabled = true or false) retrieved from the database for that particular account. I have tried to accomplish it via this code:

```
<label>Status</label>
<div class = "control-group">
<div class="controls radio-group" id="status" name = "status">
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" [checked] = "account.enabled === true" name="optradio1" formControlName="status" [value] = "true">Actief
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" [checked] = "account.enabled === false" name="optradio1" formControlName="status" [value] = "false">Inactief
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

But it doesen't automatically check the radiobutton corresponding to the last saved radiobutton value.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular radio button :checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238019/angular-radio-button-checked)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an `event listener` take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8922002/3998484) stack overflow question that uses a loop to attach listeners to multiple radio buttons.

The listener will listen for a change of value to the button and will run a function when that occurs.

In that function set the radio button's new value to whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

don't use the `event listener`, it would break rule ,elegant and it pretty rude.

In addition,bad performance and slowly when you `spy`(listen) every single event.

Fortunately, `angular` supported the native event trigger to complete the radio button to deal `ngModel`

*html*

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" [checked] = "account.enabled" name="optradio1" formControlName="status" [value] = "true" (change)="account.enabled=!account.enabled" />Actief
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" [checked] = "!account.enabled" name="optradio1" formControlName="status" [value] = "false" (change)="account.enabled=!account.enabled" />Inactief
</label>
```

Despite use the `(change)` , there is more simple way to deal it, make a component yourself or build a `Directive`(really tough if you want to use `CDK`).