# Switching bootstrap radio buttons with Angular 2+ from the template

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to switch a set of radio buttons with angular class and attribute statements. When I click the buttons I can see the `active` class being added and removed as required and the `checked` attribute being set too. However the radio button doesn't actually get checked.

```
<div class="btn-group " data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active': s}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" (click)="s=true" [attr.checked]="s"> Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active': !s}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"(click)="s=false" [attr.checked]="!s"> No
  </label>
</div>
```

[Live demo of the problem](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srzvcu)

Using Angular 5, bootstrap 4.0.0

EDIT: Not a duplicate because I know there are other ways of doing it. But I am trying to figure out why the above method isn't working.

EDIT2: If I bind to a function with `(click)="doSomething()"` it works! but also causes an error because the function isn't defined. If I create the function it stops working again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular radio button :checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238019/angular-radio-button-checked)

Comment: @Zze Not asking how to do it byt why my method isn't working.

Comment: This way is simpler and seems to be making the required changes to the DOM. Only problem is it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `[checked]`  instead of `[attr.checked]`?

Comment: Yep. That doesn't work either. Just trying to make a plunker now.

Comment: @charsi I prefer [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcrejn) over plunkr these days. It has much better compiler errors and warning etc.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srzvcu

Comment: Interestingly, if the value is set with a method instead of assigned directly in the template, [it works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcqxuv).

Comment: @ConnorsFan I am seeing some more weirdness. Even if I do it within the template but bind a function to the click it works. Has to be a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange things happen when processing the `click` event. If the flag value is set directly in the template, the radio buttons are not checked correctly:

```
(click)="s = false"
```

but if the flag is set with a method, then everything works well:

```
(click)="setValue(false)"
```

You may prefer to handle the `change` event, which seems to [work correctly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecjzqb) all the time:

```
(change)="s = false"
```

A better alternative is to use data binding with `ngModel`, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-41ygu9):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="s">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" [(ngModel)]="s" [value]="true"> Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="!s">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" [(ngModel)]="s" [value]="false"> No
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a better solution. You might appreciate the simplicity. Because the user is actually going to click the radio button, they had it with ngmodel which passes data into field, which you don't want.

html

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="View Type">
   <button type="button" [class.active]="sortClass" (click)="switch(1)" class="btn btn-secondary">
      <span>Grid</span>
   </button>
   <button type="button" [class.active]="listClass" (click)="switch(2)" class="btn btn-secondary">
      <span>List</span>
   </button>
 </div>
```

component.ts

```
// Create variables
private sortClass: boolean;
private listClass: boolean;

// INITIALIZE TRUE / FALSE for both variables
constructor() {
    this.sortClass = false;
    this.listClass = true;
}

switch(i) {
        if (i === 1) {
            this.sortClass = !this.sortClass
            this.listClass = !this.listClass
        } else {
            this.listClass = !this.listClass
            this.sortClass = !this.sortClass
        }
    }
```

Then you will see one active, and the other false. When you click they will alternative true/false.

Comment: Good approach, but the question is looking for a way to do this from just the template.

Answer (score 0):

changing the attribute must be happening outside of Angular's context so you need to NgZone.run()

https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

```js
blah() {
    this.zone.run(() => { console.log("boom!"); });
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group " data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active': s}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" (click)="s=true; blah();" [attr.checked]="s === 'true' ? true : false"> Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'active': !s}">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"(click)="s=false; blah();" [attr.checked]="s === 'false' ? true : false"> No
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't quite understand how to apply this. I am new to angular so don't understand how 'angular's context' figures into this. Is switching the radio not possible from within the template?

Comment: If it is possible, would you mind forking the [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srzvcu) to show your solution.